# reading decimal number from textfile using fscaf c proramming

Tags: c, scanf

Hi I am new to c programming and I am having trouble getting the decimal number in the text file using the fscanf. It always give me 2 numbers instead of one
Example: in the text file there is: 2.5

but in the result it game me 1 char type(2.) and 1 integer type(5);

how can I get the decimal number as int?

```
while((val = fscanf(stdin,"%d%c",&num ,&c)))
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: You can use the format specifier `%d%*c%d` (read an integer, ignore a character, read an integer). Make sure both `num` and `c` are of type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

2.5 is not an int value.  You must scan and store it as a floating-point type, preferably double:

```
int n;
double d;
FILE *infile;
...
n = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &d);
if (n!=1) 
{ 
    ... handle bad input ... 
}
```

You can then cast to int, or whatever.  The reason for double is that float can't represent all 32-bit int values exactly.

Edit: To test for a double value being integral, just compare d == (int)d.  That will be true if and only if d is exactly equal to an integer.

PS: I missed the use of stdin in the example line.  It's usual to use scanf() to scan from stdin.  Now it looks more like maybe there's keyboard input with a chance of typing errors.  For that, I tend to use fgets() to get a string and sscanf() to convert and validate:

```
char input[82];
...
while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != NULL)
{
    int value;
    char ignore;
    int n = sscanf(input, "%d %c", &value, &ignore);
    if (n != 1)
    { ... invalid input: print message & continue; }
    ... do something with value 
}
```

Comment: what if there is an int in the text file?

Comment: @PoldzKerk the "%lf" will also scan integer text like "2" into a double. The double value will be 2.0.

Comment: @CharlieBurns Can I scan double when I have this code? cause I need to have this piece of code to scan integers chars and double while((val = fscanf(stdin,"%d%c",&num ,&c)))

Comment: No, use the fscanf() that Mike gave you in his answer. That will scan integers and doubles.

Comment: @CharlieBurns but I can't scan int with chars now if I only put that code

Comment: To answer anymore we need to see more of your code and the input file. And what you expect to see and what you are observing.

Comment: @CharlieBurns The return value of scanf/fscanf/sscanf is NOT the value that was scanned, by the way. It is the count of the number of values that were successfully scanned and stored.  If you are expecting 1 value, you should test for the _scanf() return value being exactly 1.

Comment: @PoldzKerk Oops, that last should have been sent to you, not CB. Apologies to both.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting
num == 2 and c == 5 is because you are trying to read integer first and then a char,
now your input buffer contains **2**, **.**, **5**

Reading an integer stops when a '**.**' is encountered and '**.**' is flushed from the input buffer, next you are trying to read a character and hence **'5'** goes into c.

You can do something like this

```
float tmp;
int num;
char c;
scanf("%f%c", &tmp, &c);
num = tmp; //this will truncate the decimal part
```

Note: Be careful that if you hit enter after reading a character and immediately you try to read a character again, the newline character still resides in the input buffer and will be read as next character, you will have to explicitly flush it

Answer (score 0):

For char is better to use fgetc() than fscanf(fin,"%c);
Use it like that :

```
c=fgetc(fi); or fputc(c,fout);
```